# How do I print a list in python to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of data with multiple rows that I have read from an excel file I then read it in to a list.
Now, I would like to print this list to another text file and save it and then print out html to another file. 
Then I would like to make a html file so I can make a table so that it has 4 rows and each row would contain one cell of data.

Note: I am using python 3.

I have tried this so far but it does not seem to work.

```
data = ['Course name', 'Course Type', 'Tutor']
       ['English',    , 'Languages' , 'Mr A']
       ['Geography'   , 'Humanities', 'Mr B']
       ['Civil Engineering' , 'Engineering', 'Mr C']

f = open("SomeData.csv", 'w')
for row in mylist:
    print(row,file=f)
```

Comment: You show `data` as one list, some "naked" lists, but use `mylist` in your loop.

Comment: It's a good idea to the the `csv` module to write csv files. Then you don't need to worry if one of the fields contains a character that needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

Your code list initialization translates to:

```
data = ['Course name', 'Course Type', 'Tutor']

['English',    , 'Languages' , 'Mr A']             # Just a statement
['Geography'   , 'Humanities', 'Mr B']             # Just a statement
['Civil Engineering' , 'Engineering', 'Mr C']      # Just a statement
```

but you need to make a list of lists:

```
data = [
    ['Course name', 'Course Type', 'Tutor'],
    ['English', 'Languages' , 'Mr A'],
    ['Geography', 'Humanities', 'Mr B'],
    ['Civil Engineering', 'Engineering', 'Mr C']
]
```

Next, you can write your data to file:

```
f = open("output.txt", "w")
for row in data:
    print(", ".join(row), file=f)
f.close()
```

Comment: You can avoid the inner loop by just doing:  `print(", ".join(row), file=f)`, and you can remove the trailing print.

Comment: I have decided to add student ID but I am getting an error saying list indices must be integers not tuple.   data = [
    ['Student ID','Course name', 'Course Type', 'Tutor'],
    ['12345','English', 'Languages' , 'Mr A'],
    ['34598','Geography', 'Humanities', 'Mr B'],
    ['23976','Civil Engineering', 'Engineering', 'Mr C']
]

Comment: If that really is OP's code, shouldn't it raise an `IndentationError`?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky, I have tried it but there is no data in the file when I open it.

Comment: Are you trying to open the file before you have closed it in python? (While it is still running?)

Comment: Not sure but I open it after I see this on the output screen *** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***

Comment: What is going on here? Are you testing this from an interactive interp? If so you need to close or flush the file so it commits the writes to disk from the buffer

Comment: Sounds like the OP is using some kind of IDE like PyScripter.

Comment: Yes I am using a PyScripter

Answer (score 2):

Once you get your list correctly assembled as noted in the above answer, you can do the output part  as mentioned, or like this:

```
f = open("SomeData.csv", 'w')
for row in data:
    f.write(",".join(row)+",")
f.close()
```

Here is a hint on an easy way to do the HTML output portion in the same manner as the CSV portion.

```
f = open("output.html", 'w')
f.write("<html><table>")
for row in data:
    f.write("<tr><td>"+"</td><td>".join(row)+"</td></tr>")
f.write("</table></html>")
f.close()
```

There is also a python csv library that helps with more in-depth CSV needs: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html

Comment: Thanks - I have tried it, but when a load the page, it is not displayed in a table format instead it is displayed next to each other without spaces.

Comment: You'd still need the tags to make it a legitimate document, i.e. <html><table>...</table></html>

Comment: I don't think the `"<tr><td>"+"</td><td>".join(row)+"</td></tr>"` does what you expect...and need.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

class CoolFileWriter:
    """reads a csv file and writes a text or html file"""
    def __init__(self, csv_file, txt_out='out.txt', html_out='out.html'):
        self.csv_file = csv_file
        self.txt_out = txt_out
        self.html_out = html_out
        self.content = []

    def read_csv(self):
        with open(self.csv_file, newline='') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                self.content.append(row)

    def write_txt(self):
        f = open(self.txt_out, 'w')
        for row in self.content:
            f.write(', '.join(row) + '\n')
        f.close()

    def write_html(self):
        html_pre="""
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Table Data</title>
<style>
#newspaper-a
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 45px;
    width: 480px;
    text-align: left;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #69c;
}
#newspaper-a th
{
    padding: 12px 17px 12px 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #039;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #69c;
}
#newspaper-a td
{
    padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
    color: #669;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="newspaper-a">
"""
        html_post="""
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""
        f = open(self.html_out, 'w')
        f.write(html_pre)
        th=True
        for row in self.content:
            if (th):
                f.write("<tr>\n\t<th>"+"</th>\n\t<th>".join(row)+"</th>\n</tr>\n")
                th=False
            else:
                f.write("<tr>\n\t<td>"+"</td>\n\t<td>".join(row)+"</td>\n</tr>\n")
        f.write(html_post)
        f.close()

f = CoolFileWriter('excel.csv', 'data.txt', 'data.html')

f.read_csv()
f.write_txt()
f.write_html()
```

The table style comes from [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/). :-)